# Javascript regex matches from wrong starting point

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the below source text, using javascript, I need to match the below excerpt.

**My Regex** (what I have so far):

```
subject.match(/\s\([A-Z]{3}\)[\w\s]+\([A-Z]{3}\)[\s\S]*?\([A-Z]\)/)
```

**Excerpt** (match I need to get):

```
Atlanta (ATL) to Charlotte (CLT) — Wed, Dec 17
American Airlines Inc. 658
Dep: 5:50 am
Arr: 6:57 am
1h 7m
Airbus A321
Economy (L)
```

**Source** (group of text to get match from, taken from textarea):

```
Atlanta (ATL) to Cancun (CUN) — Wed, Dec 17
Long layover

Atlanta (ATL) to Charlotte (CLT) — Wed, Dec 17
American Airlines Inc. 658
Dep: 5:50 am
Arr: 6:57 am
1h 7m
Airbus A321
Economy (L)
OPERATED BY US AIRWAYS
Layover in CLT
2h 33m

Charlotte (CLT) to Cancun (CUN) — Wed, Dec 17
American Airlines Inc. 883
Dep: 9:30 am
Arr: 11:26 am
2h 56m
Boeing 767
Economy (L)
Food for Purchase
OPERATED BY US AIRWAYS
Cancun (CUN) to Atlanta (ATL) — Wed, Dec 24
Long layover

Cancun (CUN) to Miami (MIA) — Wed, Dec 24
American Airlines Inc. 1157
Dep: 12:01 pm
Arr: 2:40 pm
1h 39m
Boeing 737
Economy (G)
Layover in MIA
3h 40m

Miami (MIA) to Atlanta (ATL) — Wed, Dec 24
American Airlines Inc. 349
Dep: 6:20 pm
Arr: 8:25 pm
2h 5m
Boeing 737
Economy (G)
```

**My problem**: my regex matches from the wrong starting point when certain lines are duplicated in the source text. See screenshot below taken from RegexBuddy's test panel for a better explanation.
How can I change my regex to match starting at the point indicated?

[image]

Comment: Split the text by `\n\n`, then process record by record? It is much simpler in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem with this:

```
subject.match(/\s\([A-Z]{3}\)[\w\s]+\([A-Z]{3}\).*\n(?:.{3,}\n)*.*\([A-Z]\)/)
```

Just completed the first line with non newline elements (0 or more), then matched a newline (just 1), and then matched all lines with length of 3 or more, untill last (had to fill it too).

PD: There's a non capturing group there, harmless.

Comment: Weird, when testing in regexBuddy, this doesnt match but when used in browser on jsfiddle it does match  http://jsfiddle.net/7p4kpoo7/1/

Comment: Never used "regexBuddy", but for Regex testing I strongly recommend http://www.regexr.com/
The only "but" is that it tests generic Regex, not language specific ones, so you have to know the differences (almost the same).

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems of your regex is that you allowed anything, including the newlines, before the second right parenthesis. That's causing the ending match to the string "(L)". If you can include in your requirements that at least three lines of text are needed to start a match, then the following may work for you:

```
subject.match(/\s\([A-Z]{3}\)[^\r\n]+\([A-Z]{3}\)([^\r\n]+[\r\n]){3,}/);
```